# Simplest Dialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the simplest kind, VB's `MsgBox "Hello, World."`  (VB automatically apends an [OK] button to that.)

But the following doesn't display at all (i.e., it doesn't work), and I don't know if it can be made simpler either:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SomeClass.this);
builder.setMessage("Hello, World.")
.setCancelable(true)
.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
}
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

The last statement is also debugged by Eclipse:  The local variable alert is never read.

Yes I'm a noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call show() method on AlertDialog.Builder........show();
in the end

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(SomeClass.this);
builder.setMessage("Hello, World.")
.setCancelable(true)
.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
}
}).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try give it a `alert.show();` after `AlertDialog alert = builder.create();`